# react-native send push notification error

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native

I'm encountering an issue while implementing push notifications in react-native and I have a question about it.

There's no problem with receiving push notifications. However, I'm facing an issue with sending them. I've tried implementing it using both Firebase Admin SDK and FCM HTTP v1 API, but I'm consistently encountering the following error for both:

For Firebase Admin SDK, I installed the firebase-admin package and for FCM HTTP v1 API, I used the googleapis package. Even after importing as below:

-- Firebase Admin SDK

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase-admin/app";
// OR
const { initializeApp } = require("firebase-admin/app");
```

-- FCM HTTP v1 API

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');
```

-- Firebase Admin SDK Error Message

```
undefined Unable to resolve module fs from /Users/user/Projects/project/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/app/lifecycle.js: fs could not be found within the project or in these directories:
```

-- FCM HTTP v1 API Error Message

```
undefined Unable to resolve module fs from /Users/user/Projects/project/node_modules/googleapis-common/build/src/discovery.js: fs could not be found within the project or in these directories:
```

Upon checking on Google, I found a response suggesting:

"Firebase Admin SDK and googleapis are used for backend development in Node.js and are not usable in React Native. For sending push notifications using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) in React Native, it's recommended to use Firebase JavaScript SDK."

It seems that the Firebase JavaScript SDK (firebase) is intended for web usage (prompting an error message saying 'This browser is not supported').

Do you happen to have any insights or solutions to the issue I'm facing?
I'd greatly appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: You're correct, the googleapis package is built for web. Use the react-native-firebase package instead.